# Layering repeated logic atop methods (OOP architecture)

Tags: oop, architecture, abstraction, object-oriented-analysis

All 3 methods below need to perform a cache check (pseudo code):

```
public class Calculus
{
    private map<string, IntegralResult> _intCache;
    private map<string, DerivativeResult> _derCache;
    private map<string, decimal> _mulCache;

    public IntegralResult integrate(string func)
    {
        // result already cached?
        if (_intCache.contains(func)) return _intCache.get(func);

        // perform integration

        _intCache.put(func, result);
        return result;
    }

    public DerivativeResult derivative(string func)
    {
        // result already cached?
        if (_derCache.contains(func)) return _derCache.get(func);

        // perform derivative

        _derCache.put(func, result);
        return result;
    }

    /*  notice private  */
    private decimal multiply(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        // result already cached?
        string key = (string)a + ";" + (string)b;
        if (_mulCache.contains(key)) return _mulCache.get(key);

        // perform multiplication

        _mulCache.put(key, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

What's the best way to rewrite this class? I am looking for applicable design patterns that can be used to layer a specific logic on top of methods.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Any language that supports OOP.

Comment: So are you looking for an abstract, theoretical answer, or a piece of code?

Comment: The answer will vary widely based on language (and whether you consider functional programming to be OOP).

Comment: Abstract theoretical answer. Design patters are not language specific right?

Comment: Some features (such as templates, generics, attributes) which can be very relevant here either exists or not, and to varying degree, depending on language.

Comment: I  was hoping for a design pattern (since this problem is not exclusive to a single programming language) but if you must please assume Java -since it's a universal language with a few derivatives.